# visreg2d color bar title

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'm trying to add a legend title to the color bar produced by visreg2d, but I can't find documentation on how. Any advice is helpful!

Some example code:

```
 library(visreg)
    fit.heat <- lm(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp, data = airquality)
    visreg2d(fit.heat, "Wind", "Temp", plot.type = "image")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack but based on this [closed github issue](https://github.com/pbreheny/visreg/issues/42), I found a bit of a workaround with treating the object as a plot as a ggplot2 object.

```
library(visreg)

fit.heat <- lm(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp, data = airquality)
visreg2d(fit.heat, "Wind", "Temp", plot.type = "gg")
```

Produces this plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Stedy! When I tried this with my actual data, it still gives the title of the color bar as f(x,y) (e.g. f(temp,wind)). I can change it if I use scale_fill_gradient(name = "Z") but then it replaces the nice blue-to-red scale of visreg with a ggplot gradient scale.  I guess I just need to find a way recreate this gradient color scheme in ggplot.

Comment: One other option could be opening a github issue, the maintainer seems like he has a pretty good response rate